# Passing a button to an event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, button, eventhandler

I want to pass a button to an event handler outside the scope of the button object.

For example:

```
void OnClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button123.text="changed";
}
```

So I want my click to change the text of a button passed to it. Is there a way to do this other than having the button in scope- can I pass the button object to the event handler somehow?

Comment: What is the `sender` parameter? Isn't that the button that was clicked?

Comment: ^^ I've tried sender.text="changed" to no avail:

Comment: There is not enough context here. Which button is being clicked? The one you also want to change? Or some other button? Are both buttons in the same class? Or are they in different classes? If they are in different classes, what is the relationship between those two classes? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of your question but here is an attempt to answer it.

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Text = "changed";
    }
}
```

This allow you to handle any button click and it will change that buttons text.

Comment: Oakcool, that has done the trick! Thankyou, is this an example of 'boxing' this object?

Comment: Yes, boxing occurs every time you put an object inside another object of different type.